# How can I start a new Basecamp Classic account?

Tags: basecamp, registration

With the new Basecamp (since Jan 2012) the old Basecamp is labelled 'Basecamp Classic'. For a new project starting now I would like to use some functionality available only in Basecamp Classic and not (yet) in the new one.

Is there a way I can still open an account which uses Basecamp Classic?

<sub>When I normally register I get the new one, no questions asked.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the signup form for Basecamp Classic: https://signup.37signals.com/basecamp/Free/signup/

I just registered an account and it (still) works.